# Store domain in one place in angular js service

Tags: angularjs

I have the following example method in angular service:

```
 function send(data) {

         return $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: 'https://test.domain/test/send',
             data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data)

         });
     }
```

The domain that is `https://test.domain/test` is the same for all the services in my app. I do not want to write it every time in every services. I can abstract it in a constant and inject it in every service but I wonder if there is more clever solution. Is it possible to store the domain part in an interceptor or any other suggestions are welcome. Please provide code examples as I am quite new to angular. Thanks

Comment: I'd say rather than abstracting the values out into a constant, you should abstract the `$http` call into a service. Then you can just inject that service into all of your other services in place of `$http`.

Comment: can You provide a sample please

Comment: Will post as an answer, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Done! Hopefully that'll give you an idea of what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say rather than abstracting the values out into a constant, you should abstract the `$http` call into a service. Then you can just inject that service into all of your other services in place of `$http`. For example:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory("myHttp", ["$http", function ($http) {
    return function (config) {
        config.url = "https://test.domain/test" + config.url;
        return $http(config);
    };
}]);
```

So effectively what this service is doing is proxying calls to `$http`, but prepending your common URL to the beginning - this would allow you to change your example code to:

```
function send(data) {
    return myHttp({
         method: 'POST',
         url: '/send',
         data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data)
    });
}
```

Of course, this is just one example of how you could do an abstraction like this - the `myHttp` service could take any form you like, depending on what would be most convenient for you. I think this is a better solution than using an interceptor in this case, as it allows you to pick and choose when you use it, rather than it being applied to every single HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed.

Comment: @MDB: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

create an interceptor and on requests change the url.

```
angular.module('app').factory('domainInterceptorService', [
function () {

    var request = function (config) {

            config.url = 'https://test.domain/' + config.url;

        }
        return config;
    }

return {request: request};
});
```

Comment: thanks, I am doing this in the moment but I do not want to inject the constant in every possible service as I wrote in my original question.

Comment: very near to what I want to do. The problem is that as expected the domain is appended on every service call. So when I try to get my html templates - my request is - > 'https://test.domain/main.html' which is not intended. Can I somehow restrict this to only my $http calls

Comment: simple solution is to filter the url in the interceptor but this is not ok

Comment: I guess you could look at the given part and decide from there what domain to use